# Using liquid metal thermal paste on copper aluminum combination heat sink

Tags: cpu, cooling, overheating, heatsink, thermal-paste

I have this aluminum - copper combination heat sink for the processor of my desktop computer, can I use the liquid metal thermal paste on it?

[image]

Specifically it is the [thermal grizzly conductonaut](https://www.lazada.com.ph/products/thermal-grizzly-conductonaut-high-performance-thermal-paste-liquid-metal-1g-i294994729-s489868799.html?mp=1) thermal paste. There is a big and multiple warning that says

[image]

[image]

I am not that technical when it comes to hardware so I really dont know the physical appearances of the stated warnings such as nickel plated copper floors, coolers with direct heatpipe touch, CPU heatspreader made out of nickel plated copper.

[image]

Upon searching I know that nickel is silver in color, copper are orange and aluminum are grayish in color. But I cant any instances where they use a copper - aluminum combination on a liquid metal thermal paste. It would be very helpful if u can put a picture of it with its descriptions.

Comment: Post this on Electrical Engineering SE.....

Comment: The first time I've posted this question is on [hardware rec](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/13632/using-liquid-metal-thermal-paste-on-copper-aluminum-combination-heat-sink) and they said that I should post this here. Is it really this hard to ask some questions here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you should not use liquid metal with this heat sink. It is not easy to keep the liquid metal on only the copper core of this type of heat sink without any getting onto the aluminum parts.

Also, if I were you I would not be using somewhat expensive liquid-metal TIM on a basic, stock CPU cooler. You'd be much better off buying a tower cooler (ten or twenty degree difference) before buying better thermal interface material (one or two degree difference).

Comment: Thank you for your answer sir, assuming that the liquid metal would not fall on the aluminum part, do you think the liquid metal is safe on copper? I am thinking on applying a very small amount in the center so I can use what I bought. Coz currently I dont have any budget left.

Comment: If you can keep it on the copper it should be fine.

Answer (score -1):

theres no reason why you cant , ive used on stock coolers and never had any issues what so ever in fact im using it on a lloy cooler atm , unless ur thinking of not ever checking on the thermal paste ever  you shouldnt have a ny issues as long as you reapply as needed  when it goes dry and hard af i highly doubt your going to run it for years without checking or reapplying soi there wont be an issue just dont get it on ya board etc ull regret it

Its like telkling someone they cant run 91 because itll harm there engine  under normal pretenses its utter crap

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: “theres no reason why you can’t” - There are several reasons you shouldn’t use Liquid Metal on such a low quality heat sink. The amount of spelling and grammatical errors in your answer is staggering. Low quality answers with the amount of slang, grammatical, and misspelled words justified a downvote. Submitting multiple low quality answers will result in an answer ban